# Querying dbpedia timeout Exception

Tags: .net, http, semantic-web

I am trying to do queries on dbpedia, the queries are usually too long, like this:

```
Select * WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Inception> ?pf1 ?of1 . ?of1 ?pf2 ?middle . <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Batman> ?ps1 ?middle .  FILTER ((!isLiteral(?middle)) && (?middle != <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Inception> ) && (?middle != <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Batman> ) && (!isLiteral(?of1)) && (?of1 != <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Inception> ) && (?of1 != <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Batman> ) ). }LIMIT 100
```

I am using the [dotnetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/) dll to do the SPARQL query, the queries give a timeout Exception, I tried to query on [dbpedia's SPARQL Querying tool](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) , it also gives:

```
Virtuoso S1T00 Error SR171: Transaction timed out
```

I saw a similar [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261510/timeout-query-hangs-while-executing-sparql-query-to-dbpedia-from-jena) here, the [Live](http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql) website works, but I need to do it live via dbpedia, I don't want to dowload the dbpedia dump locally.

If I can somehow make the timout longer, So I wait for the results to come, I think that would solve my problem

Comment: What do you mean by "the Live website works"? Does your query give a result when you send it to the DBpedia Live endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the [documentation](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/content.asp?pageID=Querying%20with%20SPARQL)? Specifically,

> If you use a SparqlQuery object you have the option of setting its behaviour with regards to execution timeout. Since some queries can take a very long time to run it is often sensible to limit how long queries can run for, the Timeout property of the SparqlQuery allows you to specify the timeout. If you wish to get results back even when a timeout occurs then you can set the PartialResultsOnTimeout property to ensure you get some results even if a timeout occurs.

Comment: setting the timeout property doesn't work, it still times out.